# Why can't two different clients comunicate using my expressjs/socket.io server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm a sort of beginner with websockets in general, i've managed to make it work before but now trying to apply it to a real project, i've been stuck with this problem. I have started a websocket server using socket.io within my express backend. Everything seems to be working fine but only i can see the messages being sent. If i connect to it, i am able to send messages and have the server receive them and even send it back to me through a different event, but every other client connected to the same server listening to the same events don't ever receive anything. It might be something very trivial that i am overlooking but i can not figure it out. Thanks in advance.

I initialized my server with the following code:

```
var express = require('express')
var http = require('http')
var cors = require('cors')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')


var app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app)

var socket = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    }})

    var io = socket.listen(server);

var PORT = 1234


io.on('connection', (socket) => {

console.log("An user has joined!")

    socket.on("newMessage", (data) => {
    console.log("the message: " +  data)

    socket.emit('aabc', data)
    console.log("a message has been sent.")
 
    
  });
  
   });


server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

The "newMessage" event is sent by a different component, and the server receives it succesfully, everything seems to be working fine according to the logs. And this is how i implemented a method to listen to the emitted events with my react app:

```
 useEffect(() => {

  
    const socket = io('http://localhost:1234/');
  
    socket.on('aabc', (data: any) => {
        console.log("This is the message: " + data)

}, []);
```

As stated before i receive the messages i sent, on my own console, but none of the other users do. Any clue of what i could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To broadcast to all connected clients, use:

```js
io.emit(“•••”);
```

To broadcast to a specific room, use:

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.join("some room");
});
io.to("some room").emit(“•••”);
```

- [Broadcasting events](https://socket.io/docs/v4/broadcasting-events/)
- [Rooms](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/)

Comment: Thank you that was actually it! just had to send it with io.emit()